# How to restrict others to recover my personal files

Tags: data-recovery

There are lot of "Undo delete" softwares available in the market.
My thought is: how to restrict others to recover my personal files.
For example, if I give my mobile phone(eg: Samsung Galaxy S3, 16GB) to repair. First I will do a software reset, then I will copy a big file to fill my phones memory. The file may be an unusable file like a video file copied multiple times to make it big as the phone memory. If a single file have 100MB, the total folder may contain 160 files 160x100MB ~ 16GB.

Will this idea really restrict others to recover my files ?

Comment: This question is very platform dependent. Even between Linux and Windows you should go differently about this. Questions regarding mobile phones are out of scope on SuperUser, but your approach is what most data removal tools do. However, make sure the files have different content as the OS might try to deduplicate them and only store the file once (leaving a lot of unused space).

Answer (score 0):

Recovery of data from flash memory is extremely unfeasible once the blocks themselves have been cleared.

For example, if you put lots of secret stuff on an SD card, and delete them, the blocks are still there, but if you fill the SD card with other data, the previous data will be unrecoverable.

Flash memory is also used in phones, and the same principle applies, but depending on the phone, you may not be able to access all the storage as Android has one area for apps and another for generic files and media.

If you want to make sure pictures are unrecoverable, it's probably sufficient to fill the phone storage with garbage data.